# Can I use Android PrintManager for any kind of printer?

Tags: android, printing

I'm buying a printer for a POS system I'm building. Can I use Android PrintManager API for any printer? If not, how do I know which printer is supported? (The printer I'm planning to buy says it support ESC/POS commands)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use Android PrintManager API for any printer?

No.

> how do I know which printer is supported?

Ask the printer manufacturer if they have an Android app that offers print services for their printer. This fills the same basic role as would a print driver on, say, Windows.

Other possibilities include:

- the manufacturer does not support `PrintManager` but does have some other API that they recommend that you use on Android
- some third party has a `PrintManager`-compatible app for this printer, perhaps using that other API from the manufacturer